# Express.js Router middleware re-ordering

Tags: node.js, express

In `Express.js`, is there a standard way to re-order the middleware registered on an `express#Router` object? I have a situation where it is possible to dynamically register static asset directories that should be served by the app via `express.static()`. However, the `Router#use()` method (which I'm using to register the new asset directories) always puts middleware at the end of `Router#stack`. I want this to be at the beginning. Is there any way to achieve this?

I have a working implementation that basically traverses the current Router's `stack` in reverse, picks the first middleware called `staticMiddleware`, and moves it from that location to the front of the array. This works, but is obviously dependent on the internals of `Route`. I'm hoping there's another, more standard way to achieve the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to just have a custom route at the beginning of the order that can examine the path, compare it to a list of directories you want to serve (that can change over time) and then serve the static content if its path matches.

This would just be a smarter version of `express.static()` that works off a dynamic path list rather than only a pre-defined path.  There isn't much to `express.static()` so you can just copy it into your function and make it smarter.

---

It is apparently possible to crack into the stack of middleware and modify the order.  I don't know if this is a supported capability or just something unsupported that people have figured out (that could break in the future).  Here's one article that discusses this: https://www.exratione.com/2013/03/nodejs-abusing-express-3-to-enable-late-addition-of-middleware/

Comment: I ended up _extending_ `express.static()` like you suggested, and it worked out great, so marking your answer as accepted! The solution I had earlier was similar to the one mentioned in the blog post you listed, but I ditched it for the modified `express.static()` solution. Thanks!